# Problem with bootloader application for PIC18F452

Tags: pic, bootloader

I want to program my PIC18F452 from long distances using a SIM808. By searching on the net I found out that I should write two different programs: a bootloader program and the main program.

For the bootloader, I'm using the application and the tutorial in this [link](https://github.com/MicrochipC/Microchip_PIC_Bootloader_PIC18Fx52_TruTrack).

Now my problem is that the application opens the port, but when I want to program the PIC it shows an error saying "connection not acknowledged". What might be the problem?

PS:  I programmed the bootloader hex file onto the PIC. The PIC is powered by a DC power supply that is connected to a 3.3 V regulator. I connected the rx of the PIC to the tx of the CP2102 and the tx of the PIC to the rx of the CP2102 and also connected the ground of the CP2102 to the ground of the PIC.

Comment: Literally anything could be the problem. Did you flash the bootloader onto the PIC? How is the PIC powered and connected to the serial port etc? Also, 75% of your post is completely irrelevant for the question. I´d suggest removing some irrelevant text and add some actually relevant information regarding the specific question.

Comment: @salar1991 this is a Q&A site, not a forum ... all the information belongs in the question ... it does not belong in comments ... please edit your question and delete the comment